# Spotify Apps 1.0 setItem not working

Tags: javascript, requirejs, spotify

I have some Spotify app code that looks like this:

```
require(['$api/models', '$views/list#List', '$api/search#Search'], function(models, List, Search) {

var testList = function(){
    var album = models.Album.fromURI('spotify:album:6iBEe3qEjdIRz38swH7jT0');
    console.log(album);
    var list = List.forAlbum(album);
    document.body.appendChild(list.node);
    list.init();
    var al2 = models.Album.fromURI('spotify:album:5fTBlCZFI4zYOdJn1NrLgt');
    list.setItem(al2);
};

testList();

});
```

When I run it inside my Spotify app, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'null' of undefined core.js:4
```

If it helps, this is the source code for List.setItem():

```
function (a,b){if(!this.destroyed){var c=
this,d=a instanceof f.Collection;b&&(this.options.context=b);!this.lists&&d?(this.model.setCollection(a),this.dispatchEvent({type:"set-item",item:a}),this._resetContextGroup(),this.refresh()):(this.lists&&this._callForEachList("destroy"),this.destroy(),this.addEventListener("list-init",function g(){c.removeEventListener("list-init",g);c.dispatchEvent({type:"set-item",item:a});this._resetContextGroup();c._oldParentNode&&c._oldParentNode.appendChild(c.node);this.init()}),d?this._init(a):this._loadItem(a),
this.destroyed=!1)}}
```

I am using API version 1.0.0 and views 1.35.0. 
The documentation on the List class is here: https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/list-list.html
Any help appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. In my case, the error is being thrown on `list.init()`.

Answer (score 0):

A list isn't fully initialised until it has dispatched the "initialized" event. During initialisation, attributes are being set to the list's DOM element which is later read by function such as setItem. The process depends on several asynchronous calls, which is why you can't guarantee that the attributes have been set when setItem is run.

You can subscribe to the list's "initialized" event if you want to know when a list has loaded completely.

```
list.addEventListener("initialized", function(e) { 
    console.log("List is initialized");
});
```

(You can of course also try this by running setItem inside a setTimeout with a large enough delay.)

I think setItem isn't expected to be used such a short time after you've run the lists' init function, which is why this isn't a problem in most use cases. I believe setItem is usually triggered by some action from the user. The example on the Reference site is a bit unfortunate.

**Update**: This API reached end of life in 2014, and is no longer in use.